# How to add collision between the player and the image?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to make a program where the user moves with a circle using the keyboard to collect coins. What I tried so far is using an if statement to see if they collide and if they do, the user gets 1 coin and the image disappears. When I try this method, the code runs normally, but the collision doesn't happen.

```js
/* Credit: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/525131
 */
var left, right, up, down;
var coin = [];
var player, posX, posY, radius, speed, colour, gameScreen, coins;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  left = right = up = down = false;
  gameScreen = "game";
  coins = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    coin[i] = new Coin(random(width), random(height), 20, 20);
  }
  player = new Player();
}

function game() {
  background(0);
  if (left == true) {
    player.moveLeft();
  }
  if (right == true) {
    player.moveRight();
  }
  if (up == true) {
    player.moveUp();
  }
  if (down == true) {
    player.moveDown();
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    coin[i].display();
  }
  player.display();
  //player.collision();
  fill(255);
  textSize(20);
  text("Coins: " + coins, 10, 30);
}

function draw() {
  game();
}

function keyPressed() {
  // if (keyPressed) { For Processing add this line
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW || key == 'a') {
    left = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW || key == 'd') {
    right = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW || key == 'w') {
    up = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW || key == 's') {
    down = true;
  }

  // }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW || key == 'a') {
    left = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW || key == 'd') {
    right = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW || key == 'w') {
    up = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW || key == 's') {
    down = false;
  }

}

function Coin(coinX, coinY, coinR) {
  this.img = loadImage("https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Coin120.png");
  this.coinX = coinX;
  this.coinY = coinY;
  this.coinR = coinR;

  this.display = function() {
    image(this.img, this.coinX, this.coinY, this.coinR, this.coinR);
  }
}

function Player() {
  this.posX = width / 2;
  this.posY = height / 2;
  this.radius = 10;
  this.speed = 4;
  this.colour = "blue";

  this.display = function() {
    fill(this.colour);
    ellipse(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
  }
  this.moveLeft = function() {
    // posX = posX - speed;
    this.posX = constrain(this.posX - this.speed, this.radius, width - this.radius);
  }

  this.moveRight = function() {
    // posX = posX + speed;
    this.posX = constrain(this.posX + this.speed, this.radius, width - this.radius);
  }

  this.moveUp = function() {
    // posY = posY-speed;
    this.posY = constrain(this.posY - this.speed, this.radius, height - this.radius);
  }

  this.moveDown = function() {
    // posY = posY+speed;
    this.posY = constrain(this.posY + this.speed, this.radius, height - this.radius);
  }
  /*this.collision = function(){
        if (this.posX > this.coinX && this.posX < this.coinX + this.coinR && this.posY > this.coinY && this.posY < this.coinY + this.coinR){
          coins+=1;
          //Coin disappears
          
        }
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dist()` in p5 to determine the distance between the center of the two circles and then see if it smaller than the two radi combined. Once you have that you can execute whatever code is needed.

```
for (let i = 0; i < coin.length; i++) {
    if (
      dist(player.posX, player.posY, coin[i].coinX, coin[i].coinY) <
      player.radius + coin[i].coinR
    ) {
      coin.splice(i, 1);
      coins++;
      i--;
    }
  }
```

Snippet

```js
/* Credit: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/525131
 */
var left, right, up, down;
var coin = [];
var player, posX, posY, radius, speed, colour, gameScreen, coins;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  left = right = up = down = false;
  gameScreen = "game";
  coins = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    coin[i] = new Coin(random(400), random(400), 20);
  }
  player = new Player();
}

function game() {
  background(0);
  if (left == true) {
    player.moveLeft();
  }
  if (right == true) {
    player.moveRight();
  }
  if (up == true) {
    player.moveUp();
  }
  if (down == true) {
    player.moveDown();
  }
  //change to coin.length to prevent error
  for (var i = 0; i < coin.length; i++) {
    coin[i].display();
  }
  player.display();
  //player.collision();
  fill(255);
  textSize(20);
  text("Coins: " + coins, 10, 30);

  for (let i = 0; i < coin.length; i++) {
    if (
      dist(player.posX, player.posY, coin[i].coinX, coin[i].coinY) <
      player.radius + coin[i].coinR
    ) {
      coin.splice(i, 1);
      coins++;
      i--;
    }
  }
}
function draw() {
  game();
}
function keyPressed() {
  // if (keyPressed) { For Processing add this line
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW || key == "a") {
    left = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW || key == "d") {
    right = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW || key == "w") {
    up = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW || key == "s") {
    down = true;
  }

  // }
}
function keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW || key == "a") {
    left = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW || key == "d") {
    right = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW || key == "w") {
    up = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW || key == "s") {
    down = false;
  }
}

function Coin(coinX, coinY, coinR) {
  /*this.img = loadImage(
    "https://www.searchpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Game-Coins-PNG-jpeg-715x715.png"
  );*/
  this.coinX = coinX;
  this.coinY = coinY;
  this.coinR = coinR;
  this.colour = "yellow";

  this.display = function () {
    fill(this.colour);
    ellipse(this.coinX, this.coinY, this.coinR * 2, this.coinR * 2);
  };
}

function Player() {
  this.posX = width / 2;
  this.posY = height / 2;
  this.radius = 10;
  this.speed = 4;
  this.colour = "blue";

  this.display = function () {
    fill(this.colour);
    ellipse(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
  };
  this.moveLeft = function () {
    // posX = posX - speed;
    this.posX = constrain(
      this.posX - this.speed,
      this.radius,
      width - this.radius
    );
  };

  this.moveRight = function () {
    // posX = posX + speed;
    this.posX = constrain(
      this.posX + this.speed,
      this.radius,
      width - this.radius
    );
  };

  this.moveUp = function () {
    // posY = posY-speed;
    this.posY = constrain(
      this.posY - this.speed,
      this.radius,
      height - this.radius
    );
  };

  this.moveDown = function () {
    // posY = posY+speed;
    this.posY = constrain(
      this.posY + this.speed,
      this.radius,
      height - this.radius
    );
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4kV7GkNv7QR7RX9YF/olywyIgIwNvfEe2nZtfyj73HdjCUkAfOBDbcuJ/cTaN04JKRnw1YG1wnUyNKMsNgg3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `collision` function was trying to access `this.coinX`, `this.coinY`, and `this.coinR` but it was defined on `Player` which doesn't have any of those properties. You need to use a loop to check each coin for collision:

```
      this.collision = function() {
        for (let ix = 0; ix < coin.length; ix++) {
          const currentCoin = coin[ix];
          if (this.posX > currentCoin.coinX &&
            this.posX < currentCoin.coinX + currentCoin.coinR &&
            this.posY > currentCoin.coinY &&
            this.posY < currentCoin.coinY + currentCoin.coinR) {
            coins += 1;
            
            // Coin disappears:
            // delete the current coin from the array
            coin.splice(ix, 1);
            // Since the coin that was at ix + 1 is now at position ix in
            // the coin array, we need to set ix back by one.
            ix--;
          }
        }
      }
```

```js
/* Credit: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/525131
 */
var left, right, up, down;
var coin = [];
var player, posX, posY, radius, speed, colour, gameScreen, coins;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  left = right = up = down = false;
  gameScreen = "game";
  coins = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    coin[i] = new Coin(random(width), random(height), 20, 20);
  }
  player = new Player();
}

function game() {
  background(0);
  if (left == true) {
    player.moveLeft();
  }
  if (right == true) {
    player.moveRight();
  }
  if (up == true) {
    player.moveUp();
  }
  if (down == true) {
    player.moveDown();
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < coin.length; i++) {
    coin[i].display();
  }
  player.display();
  player.collision();
  fill(255);
  textSize(20);
  text("Coins: " + coins, 10, 30);
}

function draw() {
  game();
}

function keyPressed() {
  // if (keyPressed) { For Processing add this line
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW || key == 'a') {
    left = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW || key == 'd') {
    right = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW || key == 'w') {
    up = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW || key == 's') {
    down = true;
  }

  // }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW || key == 'a') {
    left = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW || key == 'd') {
    right = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW || key == 'w') {
    up = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW || key == 's') {
    down = false;
  }

}

function Coin(coinX, coinY, coinR) {
  this.img = loadImage("https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Coin120.png");
  this.coinX = coinX;
  this.coinY = coinY;
  this.coinR = coinR;

  this.display = function() {
    image(this.img, this.coinX, this.coinY, this.coinR, this.coinR);
  }
}

function Player() {
  this.posX = width / 2;
  this.posY = height / 2;
  this.radius = 10;
  this.speed = 4;
  this.colour = "blue";

  this.display = function() {
    fill(this.colour);
    ellipse(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
  }
  this.moveLeft = function() {
    // posX = posX - speed;
    this.posX = constrain(this.posX - this.speed, this.radius, width - this.radius);
  }

  this.moveRight = function() {
    // posX = posX + speed;
    this.posX = constrain(this.posX + this.speed, this.radius, width - this.radius);
  }

  this.moveUp = function() {
    // posY = posY-speed;
    this.posY = constrain(this.posY - this.speed, this.radius, height - this.radius);
  }

  this.moveDown = function() {
    // posY = posY+speed;
    this.posY = constrain(this.posY + this.speed, this.radius, height - this.radius);
  }
  this.collision = function() {
    for (let ix = 0; ix < coin.length; ix++) {
      const currentCoin = coin[ix];
      if (this.posX > currentCoin.coinX &&
        this.posX < currentCoin.coinX + currentCoin.coinR &&
        this.posY > currentCoin.coinY &&
        this.posY < currentCoin.coinY + currentCoin.coinR) {
        coins += 1;
        
        // Coin disappears:
        // delete the current coin from the array
        coin.splice(ix, 1);
        // Since the coin that was at ix + 1 is now at position ix in
        // the coin array, we need to set ix back by one.
        ix--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Justin makes a good point as well regarding simplifying the code using `dist()`